# Allow one docker container to connect with postgres running on other container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have code that has a POSTGRES_URL variable in the .env file. I have a Postgres container running with port mapping `-p 5431:5432` named `upbeat_leakey`. i have passed value like `POSTGRES_URL = postgres://postgres:83355806@localhost:5431/test`. when i start the code on localhost it ran without error and connected to database. Now, i have created a docker image of my code and when i try to build the docker image like
`sudo docker run --env POSTGRES_URL=postgres://postgres:83355806@localhost:5431/test --link upbeat_leakey -p 3000:3000 my-app:dev`  iam getting database connection error when ran.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5431
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because now your program is isolated from the rest of your system. You need to use the container name of your postgres container instead of `localhost` and also the port inside the container, as the port mapping is only valid for the host. In your case the container is probably called `upbeat_leaky`.

Also you are using the legacy `--link` system of docker and should probably switch to using networks. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) for more details.

Comment: i have even tried with ```postgres://postgres:83355806@upbeat_leaky:5431/test``` but throwed the same error

Comment: Yeah, you need to use the internal port not the mapped one. So `postgres://postgres:83355806@upbeat_leaky:5432/test`

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I removed the port number out of URL